# small string buffer for a Oracle function

Tags: oracle, function

I wrote a this function to return varchar2 from some tables.

```
create or replace function info_raum(in_name varchar2)
return varchar2
is
v_fi_name fitnesscenter.name%type;
v_num number;
v_output varchar2(2000) :='';
begin

    for rec in (select * from raum where name = in_name) 
    loop

        select name
        into v_fi_name
        from fitnesscenter
        where fitnesscenternr = rec.fitnesscenternr;

        select count(*)
        into v_num
        from ist_im
        where raumnr = rec.raumnr;

        v_output := v_output || 'Fitnesscenter: ' || v_fi_name || ' - GeräteAnz: ' || v_num || ' ---';
    end loop;

return v_output;
end;
```

Wenn I execute the code I get this error:

```
Connecting to the database developer1.
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 7
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database developer1.
```

I think this is because I need a bigger datatype for v_output. But I can not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the max size of PL/SQL VARCHAR2 as it is may be exceeding the size of 2000.

use the following:

```
V_OUTPUT    VARCHAR2(32767) := ''; -- also assignment to null is not needed here
```